# Why do I get the warning message "In plot.xy(xy, type, ...) : NAs introduced by coercion"?

Tags: r, warnings

```
plot(productivity$productivity,productivity$mammals, pch=16, col=as.numeric(productivity$region))
```

When I type this, I get the warning message.

Comment: It usually means when you enforced a class transformation, R had to coerce some into NAs. It probably happened in your `col=as.numeric(productivity$region)` argument.
I think you may have non-numeric characters in productivity$region

Answer (score 0):

Probably the warning is from `as.numeric(productivity$region)` - you can verify by running just that command. You'll get that warning if you give values to `as.numeric` that can't be converted to numeric, e.g., `as.numeric(c("1", "2"))` gives no warning, `as.numeric(c("1", "hello"))` gives the warning (and `"hello"` is converted to `NA`).